# Почему не работает функция управление плеером YouTube?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, youtube

Пытаюсь сделать сделать плеер, который автоматически запускается и проигрывает несколько видео с *YouTube* по кругу.

Но, видимо, что-то делаю неверно, и функция не отрабатывает. В чем может быть причина?

[Пример кода в fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v3qzb/14/).

```js
var playlist = ["0Bmhjf0rKe8", "jQZtk-fCWQ4", "5wosC9QLQTM"];
var whonext = 0;
var player;
function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
        height: '390',
        width: '640',
        videoId: playlist[0],
        events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
        }
    });
    whonext++;
}
function playNext() {
    player.loadVideoById({
        'videoId': playlist[whonext],
        'startSeconds': 5,
        'endSeconds': 60,
        'suggestedQuality': 'large'
    });
    whonext++;
}
function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.playVideo();
}
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data === 0) {
        playNext();
    }
}
```

```html
<iframe id="player" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="1" title="YouTube video player"
        width="640" height="390" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/5wosC9QLQTM?enablejsapi=1">
</iframe>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых - вы не подключили сам `API`, чтобы он начал хоть как-то реагировать на ваши действия.

```
<script src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
```

Во-вторых - вы инициализацию и действия делаете в функциях, но при этом нигде не вызываете эту самую инициализацию

```
onYouTubePlayerAPIReady();
```

**Итого**:

в `head` должно быть

```
<script src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
```

В `body` должно быть:

```
<iframe id="player" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="1" title="YouTube video player" width="640" height="390" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/5wosC9QLQTM?enablejsapi=1"></iframe>
```

В скрипте должно быть:

```
var playlist=["0Bmhjf0rKe8","jQZtk-fCWQ4","5wosC9QLQTM"];
var whonext=0;
var player;
function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
        height: '390',
        width: '640',
        videoId: playlist[0],
        events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
        }
    });
    whonext++;
}
function playNext(){
    player.loadVideoById({'videoId': playlist[whonext],
                          'startSeconds': 5,
                          'endSeconds': 60,
                          'suggestedQuality': 'large'});

    whonext++;
}
function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.playVideo();
}
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {        
    if(event.data === 0) {            
        playNext();
    }
}   

onYouTubePlayerAPIReady();
```

Как-то так ¯\_(ツ)_/¯   [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v3qzb/15/)